# Increment all values of

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have that variable. `var count_br = "4,7,10"`

```
            var count_ = count_br.split(",");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < count_.length; ++i) {            

                  /// Increment here each values of count_br
                  // I want to get 8,11,14
                  //for the next loop I want to get 12,15,18
                  //etc

               }
```

Each time if `i > 0` I want to increment by 4 all the values of count_br.
How could i do to increment by 4 all the values .

thanks.

Comment: You want 0th index value to be changed but you have condition to change value for index greater than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var count_br = "4,7,10";
var count_ = count_br.split(",");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < count_.length; ++i) {            
    for(let idx in count_) count_[idx] = (parseInt(count_[idx])+4).toString() 
}
console.log(count_)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should take the length of the variable... in this case 4... less 1 is 3 and use it on a for to go trougth all the positions of you array and for each iteration you add 4